# Derived Computed Data from Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, reselect

Thanks for any help!  I've been stuck on this for a while.

I have this array

```
students: [
  {studentId: 'sss1', isAthlete: true, isHonors: true, testScore: 78, studentName: 'Bobby'},
  {studentId: 'sss2', isAthlete: false, isHonors: false, testScore: 93, studentName: 'Sally'},
  {studentId: 'sss3', isAthlete: true, isHonors: true, testScore: 82, studentName: 'Mikey'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss4', isAthlete: false, isHonors: false, testScore: 88, studentName: 'Billy'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss5', isAthlete: true, isHonors: false, testScore: 91, studentName: 'Davey'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss6', isAthlete: false, isHonors: false, testScore: 94, studentName: 'Joey'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss7', isAthlete: false, isHonors: true, testScore: 97, studentName: 'Nancy'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss8', isAthlete: true, isHonors: false, testScore: 83, studentName: 'Susie'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss9', isAthlete: false, isHonors: false, testScore: 72, studentName: 'Jimmy'}, 

]
```

The above array is computed using reselect and then injected into my React component perfectly.

Now, in my react component I need to show my user this:

```
Total Student Count: 9
Total Athlete Count: 4
Total Honors Count: 3

Average Overall Score: 86.44
Average Honors Score: 85.67
Average Athlete Score: 83.5

Highest Overall Student: Nancy
Highest Honors Student: Nancy
Highest Athlete Student: Davey
```

*My Questions*
1. What is the "best practice" for *where* to make this calculation?
2. Can anyone dream up an array method to efficiently make this calculation? My actual array has hundreds of students.

Not trying to be a free-loader here but found myself writing dozens of these:

```
const athCount = students.filter(s => s.isAthlete === true).length
```

And have that tingling feeling that I'm doing it wrong.

**THANK YOU**

Comment: use `reduce` and make all your computations there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. Can anyone dream up an array method to efficiently make this calculation? My actual array has hundreds of students.

You need to iterate the array. There is no other way. However you might only do that once:

```
  let athletes = 0, honors = 0, honorScore = 0, athleteScore= 0, totalScore = 0, best = { score: 0 };
  for(const student of students){ 
   athletes += student.isAthlete;
   honors += student.isHonors;
   totalScore += student.score;
   /*...*/
   if(student.score > best.score)
      best = student;
 }
```

Comment: Works Perfectly!!  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
    const data = [
  {studentId: 'sss1', isAthlete: true, isHonors: true, testScore: 78, studentName: 'Bobby'},
  {studentId: 'sss2', isAthlete: false, isHonors: false, testScore: 93, studentName: 'Sally'},
  {studentId: 'sss3', isAthlete: true, isHonors: true, testScore: 82, studentName: 'Mikey'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss4', isAthlete: false, isHonors: false, testScore: 88, studentName: 'Billy'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss5', isAthlete: true, isHonors: false, testScore: 91, studentName: 'Davey'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss6', isAthlete: false, isHonors: false, testScore: 94, studentName: 'Joey'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss7', isAthlete: false, isHonors: true, testScore: 97, studentName: 'Nancy'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss8', isAthlete: true, isHonors: false, testScore: 83, studentName: 'Susie'}, 
  {studentId: 'sss9', isAthlete: false, isHonors: false, testScore: 72, studentName: 'Jimmy'}, 
]

const initialResult = {
  count : {
    athlete : 0,
    honors : 0,
    total : 0
  },
  accumulate : {
    athlete : 0,
    honors : 0,
    total : 0
  },
  best : {
    name : null,
    score : null
  }
};

const result = data.reduce(process, initialResult);


function process (result, record) {
  result.count.total++;
  result.accumulate.total += record.testScore;

  if (record.isAthlete) {
    result.count.athlete++;
    result.accumulate.athlete += record.testScore;
  }
  if (record.isHonors) {
    result.count.honors++;
    result.accumulate.honors += record.testScore;
  }



  let best = result.best;

  if (best.name === null && best.score === null) {
    best.name = record.studentName;
    best.score = record.testScore;
  } else {
    if (best.score < record.testScore) {
      best.name = record.studentName;
      best.score = record.testScore;
    }
  } 

  return result;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I still dont see any benefit in using reduce in such cases.

Comment: reduce is fast and doesn't mutate data

Comment: @Clay_F you have to return the result at end of reduce callback, I have updated my answer

Comment: @AngelSalazar Thanks, okay, got it working!  Thanks.  Can you think of a specific reason for using reduce instead of for loop?  The new array isn't going into state, rather, it's just taking state data and in the render method, making a new array just to show to my user.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: Without knowing how often the input data changes, I think you should put all calculations inside the `render` function. That way, the DOM is always consistent with the data. In the large majority of cases, this will work just fine and you won't notice any performance impact.

Answer 2: In this example, `_` is the [`lodash` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash).

```js
const athletes = students.filter(({isAthlete}) => isAthlete);
const athleteCount = athletes.length;

const averageScore = _.sumBy(students, 'testScore') / students.length;
const averageHonorsScore = _.sumBy(athletes, 'testScore') / students.length;

const highestSCore = _.maxBy(students, 'testScore')
const highestAthleteScore = _.maxBy(athletes, 'testScore');
```

Comment: Thank You.  1000 x cleaner than what I'd written.  Works Perfect!